# Display number of times click on screen using Gosu.button_down

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I am working on a ruby program using Gosu. I want to display the number of mouse click times every time I click on a button on the screen. Please help me with this. Thank you so much

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gosu'

module ZOrder
  BACKGROUND, MIDDLE, TOP = *0..2
end

WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400
class DemoWindow < Gosu::Window
  def initialize
    super(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, false)
    @background = Gosu::Color::WHITE
    @button_font = Gosu::Font.new(20)
    @info_font = Gosu::Font.new(10)
    @locs = [60,60]
  end

  def draw
 
    Gosu.draw_rect(0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, @background, ZOrder::BACKGROUND, mode=:default)
    if area_clicked(mouse_x, mouse_y)
      draw_line(50, 50, Gosu::Color::BLACK, 150, 50, Gosu::Color::BLACK, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
      draw_line(50, 50, Gosu::Color::BLACK, 50, 100, Gosu::Color::BLACK, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
      draw_line(150, 50, Gosu::Color::BLACK, 150, 101, Gosu::Color::BLACK, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
      draw_line(50, 100, Gosu::Color::BLACK, 150, 100, Gosu::Color::BLACK, ZOrder::TOP, mode=:default)
    end
    Gosu.draw_rect(50, 50, 100, 50, Gosu::Color::GREEN, ZOrder::MIDDLE, mode=:default)
    @button_font.draw_text("Click me", 60, 60, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
    @info_font.draw_text("mouse_x: #{mouse_x}", 0, 350, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
    @info_font.draw_text("mouse_y: #{mouse_y}", 100, 350, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK )

    if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::MsLeft
        index =0
        button = area_clicked(mouse_x, mouse_y)
        case button
        when 1
            index+=1
            @info_font.draw("Times Click: #{index}", 370, 350, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
  end
end
end
  def needs_cursor?; true; end



  def area_clicked(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    if ((mouse_x > 50 and mouse_x < 150) and (mouse_y > 50 and mouse_y < 100))
      return 1
    else
    end
  end




  def button_down(id)
    if id == Gosu::KB_ESCAPE
        close
    else
        super
    end
end
end


DemoWindow.new.show
```

Below is the code I have added. When I click on the button, it only displays the number of times click is 1, however, I need it to display the number of times I clicked on.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: I have used Gosu.button_down and the loop index+=1 but it is not working. I want the program to display the number of times I click on the button but it only display 1 even I click 100 times on the button

Comment: Could you edit your question and update it with the exact code that you've tried? (copy and paste the whole thing)

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Can you help me out please, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're setting index back to zero every time the mouse is clicked (`index =0`). You should probably set your index to zero in your `initialize` function, and make it a class variable (add `@` to the front).

Then your initialize code would be:

```
def initialize
  super(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, false)
  @background = Gosu::Color::WHITE
  @button_font = Gosu::Font.new(20)
  @info_font = Gosu::Font.new(10)
  @locs = [60,60]
  @index = 0
end
```

and the code for the mouse click would be:

```
if Gosu.button_down? Gosu::MsLeft
    button = area_clicked(mouse_x, mouse_y)
    case button
    when 1
        @index += 1
        @info_font.draw("Times Click: #{@index}", 370, 350, ZOrder::TOP, 1.0, 1.0, Gosu::Color::BLACK)
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, i didn't know about that. But now I face the new problem which is the time click is displaying on the screen too fast.

Comment: Right, remember that draw/update can be called 60 times per second by Gosu. I believe the answer is to separate your control interactions (mouse down) and move that to an update function. This function can handle a mouse down, and update state (increase index by 1). Then your draw function only looks at your current state (index = x) and draws everything.

Comment: I have used the update function as you said, but the times it increase is still so fast, can you tell me the way to control the times it increases please

Comment: The best thing to do might be to post a new question on here and link it in a comment. Make sure to copy/paste your full code on the new question.

Comment: I have controled it by using the sleep function. Thank you for the help. Have a nice day, sir!

Comment: Great, don't forget to upvote/accept answers that helped!